# Is this ASM langage?

Tags: shell, assembly, csc

So i have a csc file (cell script container)from de game GTAV on PS3.
I opened it in XSC toolbox (xsc/csc editor) and that's what i have :

```
 :Label9
enter 0 0 2 0
PushIM 0
setstatics 244
PushIM 0
setstatics 246
NOP
Call 00000015
ret 0 0

:Label1
enter 0 0 2 0
PushIM 0
CallNative WAIT 4 0
CallNative PLAYER_PED_ID 1 0
CallNative IS_PED_SITTING_IN_ANY_VEHICLE 5 0
bz 0000008e
CallNative PLAYER_PED_ID 1 0
CallNative GET_VEHICLE_PED_IS_USING 5 0
setstatics 242
getstatics 242
getstatics 243
be 00000050
CallNative PLAYER_PED_ID 1 0
CallNative GET_VEHICLE_PED_IS_USING 5 0
setstatics 243
getstatics 243
CallNative SET_VEHICLE_FIXED 4 0
getstatics 242
PushIM 0
CallNative SET_ENTITY_CAN_BE_DAMAGED 8 0
getstatics 242
PushIM 0
CallNative SET_VEHICLE_CAN_BE_VISIBLY_DAMAGED 8 0
getstatics 242
PushIM 0
CallNative SET_VEHICLE_TYRES_CAN_BURST 8 0
getstatics 242
CallNative SET_HELI_BLADES_FULL_SPEED 4 0
CallNative PLAYER_PED_ID 1 0
PushIM 1
PushIM 1
PushIM 1
PushIM 1
PushIM 1
PushIM 1
PushIM 1
PushIM 1
CallNative SET_ENTITY_PROOFS 36 0
CallNative PLAYER_PED_ID 1 0
PushIM 1
CallNative SET_PED_CAN_BE_KNOCKED_OFF_VEHICLE 8 0
NOP
NOP
Call 0000011d
```

Im not really familiar with ASM so where can i learn it ? and also what is the setstatics instruction ?

Thanks

Comment: No, this is not assembly language.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, games are developed using a "programming" language, and by programming language I mean High Level Languages(HLL). The movement of characters, vehicles, shooting, environment, everything is controlled using the HLL. But assembly(Low Level Language) plays an important role in developing the game as well. For example you want to assign a specific amount of memory for your game, or you want to minimize the cpu usage for a specific round of time, then this LLL comes in handy. You can communicate directly with the hardware using assembly or any other low level language. If you really want to learn assembly, I suggest you must learn a High level language first, to get the idea of how the programming actually works. If you want to start, you can start with C, an then learn Java. 
If you are familiar with these HLLs, then there are a number of tutorials on the internet like [this one](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/assembly_programming/).
And [this one](http://www.swansontec.com/sprogram.html) is also a greate guide for learning assembly.